# Add function not adding to Redux State

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am going to post my question here and hopefully learn something! I've been following a tutorial and do not yet have the insight into React and Redux to effectively figure out what is going on. I want to create functionality that adds and removes businesses to global state in React and Redux. From what I've Googled I know the file structures vary depending on the project so I will post all of my files here. I have them divided into actions.js, reducers.js, state.js, and store.js. I have an add Listing view with React and would like to add remove functionality to my view listings view. Here are my files:

redux/actions.js:

```
export const addListing = (newBusiness) => {
return {
    type: 'ADD_LISTING',
    value: newBusiness
}
}

export const removeListing = (index) => {
    return {
        type: 'REMOVE_LISTING',
        value: index
    }
}
```

redux/reducers.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { addBusiness, removeBusiness } from './actions'

const user = (state = null) => state

// add switch statements in here
const businesses = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_BUSINESS':
            return [ ...state, action.value ]
        case 'REMOVE_BUSINESS':
            const newState = [ ...state ]
            newState.splice(action.value, 1);
            return newState;
     default: // need this for default case
      return state 
    }
}

export default combineReducers({ user, businesses })
```

redux/state.js

```
export default {
    user: {
        username: 'test-user-1',
        email: 'test-user@example.com'
    },
    businesses: [
        {
            "id": 15,
           "name": "My pizza",
           "description":"Homemade pizza shop",
           "address": "123 Taco Street",
           "hours": "9-5"
        }
    ]
  };
```

redux/store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducers from './reducers'
import state from './state'



export default createStore(reducers, state)
```

containers/addListing.js

```
import  { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addListing } from '../redux/actions';
import AddListing from '../components/addListing'


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addListing: (business) => dispatch(addListing(business)),
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddListing)
```

containers/removeListing.js

```
import  { connect } from "react-redux";
import { removeListing } from '../redux/actions';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        removeCar: (business) => dispatch(removeListing(business)),
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(removeListing)
```

containers/Listing.js:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Listing from '../components/Listing'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        businesses: state.businesses,
        user: state.user.username
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Listing)
```

components/addListing.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { InputLabel } from '@material-ui/core'
import { Input } from '@material-ui/core'
import { FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import '../redux/state';

class addListing extends React.Component {

    state = {
        name: '',
        description: '',
        address: '',
        hours: ''
    }


    handleTextChange = (e) => {
        const newState = { ...this.state }
        newState[e.target.id] = e.target.value
        this.setState(newState)
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const payload = { ...this.state }
        console.log("THE BUSINESS", payload)
        this.props.addListing(payload)
        console.log(this.props)
    }

    componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
        if (prevState.open !== this.state.open) {
            this.setState({
                name: '',
                description: '',
                address: '',
                hours: ''
            })
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <form 
                                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                                style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', width: '350px' }}>
                                <TextField 
                                    id="name" 
                                    name="name"
                                    placeholder="Name" 
                                    value={this.state.name} 
                                    onChange={this.handleTextChange} 
                                    required />
                                <TextField 
                                    id="description" 
                                    name="description"
                                    placeholder="Description" 
                                    value={this.state.description} 
                                    onChange={this.handleTextChange} 
                                    required />
                                <TextField 
                                    id="address" 
                                    name="address"
                                    placeholder="Address" 
                                    value={this.state.address} 
                                    onChange={this.handleTextChange} 
                                    required />
                                <TextField 
                                    id="hours" 
                                    name="hours"
                                    placeholder="Hours" 
                                    value={this.state.hours} 
                                    onChange={this.handleTextChange} 
                                    required />
                                <br />
                                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
                            </form>
            </div>
          );
    }

}

export default addListing;
```

components/Listing.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    Container,
    Table,
    TableBody,
    TableCell,
    TableHead,
    TableRow
} from '@material-ui/core'
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete'
import addListing from '../containers/addListing'
import removeListing from '../containers/removeListing'
import businesses from '../redux/state'
import user from '../redux/state';


const Listing = (props) => {
    console.log(props.businesses)
    return (
        <Container maxWidth="lg" className="car-container">
            <h4>Welcome, {props.user.username}</h4>
            <div className="flex-container">
            </div>
            <Table>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Description</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Address</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Hours</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                {props.businesses.map((businesses, idx) => (
                    <TableRow key={businesses.id}>
                        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">

                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{businesses["name"]}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{businesses["description"]}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{businesses["address"]}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{businesses["hours"]}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <DeleteIcon
                                // add onClick method here

                                // onClick={props.removeCar(idx)}
                                className="icon text-red" 
                                onClick={ () => this.props.removeListing(idx)}
                                />
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Listing
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation'
import './App.css'
import Router from './Router'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux/store'

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation />
        <Router />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Login from './components/Login'
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Listing from '../src/components/Listing';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

ReactDOM.render(

        <App />,

  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

So far I know it's something simple. I am getting no errors but it just doesn't seem to add the new listings to global state. When I get to the listing view it only displays the Business I included as a default in state.js. I will try to reply in a quick manner and please let me know if more info is needed. Thanks!

Comment: I see that the names of your actions are different `ADD_LISTING` vs `ADD_BUSINESS`, `REMOVE_LISTING` vs. `REMOVE_BUSINESS`. Could it be the problem?

Comment: Hey euvs, where are the differences? There are so many moving parts to this it's overwhelming.

Comment: In the `addListing`  you have `{type: 'ADD_LISTING', ...}`, in your reducer you  have `case 'ADD_BUSINESS':`... The strings are different. They need to match. Try renaming `ADD_BUSINESS` to `ADD_LISTING`

Comment: Thanks euvs! Let me know how to add to your reputation points. Also, when I'm on the main Listings.js page and I click delete it says, 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined'. The onClick event is around line 50 of components/Listings.js. I think it has something to do with how I'm referencing the function from props.

Comment: I'll post my comments as the answer then.. so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the names of your actions are different `ADD_LISTING` vs `ADD_BUSINESS`, `REMOVE_LISTING` vs. `REMOVE_BUSINESS`.

In the `addListing` you have `{type: 'ADD_LISTING', ...}`, in your reducer you have `case 'ADD_BUSINESS':` The strings are different. They need to match. Try renaming `ADD_BUSINESS` => `ADD_LISTING`, and `REMOVE_BUSINESS`=>`REMOVE_LISTING`.

Regarding the crash on line 50. You don't need `this.` because your component is not a `class` type. Change it to `onClick={ () => props.removeListing(idx)}`.

You're missing `removeListing` in the `mapDispatchToProps`.

Also, Redux DevTools plugin for Chrome can help you a lot in debugging issues with redux..

Comment: It's giving me TypeError: props.removeListing is not a function now. So maybe it's something in my reducer?

Comment: You're missing `removeListing` in the `mapDispatchToProps` @Carlos

Comment: Are you referring to the removeListing container? There are multiple references to removeListing within that file. One of which was removeCar (from my last project) which I changed to removeListing.

Comment: Yeah... Look... I believe you need to read the redux theory or do a course. Redux has some learning curve. You need to understand what `mapDispatchToProps` is, and how it relates to component's props. Otherwise you'll be randomly copy-pasting things hoping they would magically work. Redux is not a beginner friendly framework IMO, but it is not a terribly difficult either. @Carlos